# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004 with QStack<std::map<std::string,std::string > > appending

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, qt4

I have QStack > that is getting filled all the time
from the application i guard it with QMutexLocker  , it getting filled from different threads 
the QStack is static . 
now after few inserts im getting :

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004
```

this is the function that the exception is appear

```
bool MyClass::AppendToLinks(QVector<std::map<std::string,std::string > >& linksvec)
{
    try
    {

        static QMutex mutex;
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

        //used to: be m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack+= linksvec;

        QStack<std::map<std::string,std::string > > stackTemp;
        stackTemp = m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack;
        stackTemp  << linksvec;
            // here is where the exception appear :
        m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack = stackTemp;
        locker.unlock();
        if(m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack.size()>0)
        {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    catch (std::exception const & e)
    {
        std::cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;

    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown exception." << std::endl;

    }
}
```

and this is the stack :

```
myapp.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > >,0> >::_Copy(const std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > >,0> > & _Right={...})  Line 1063 + 0x11 bytes    C++
    myapp.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > >,0> >::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > >,0> >(const std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > >,0> > & _Right={...})  Line 536  C++
    myapp.exe!QVector<std::map<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > > >::realloc(int asize=12, int aalloc=12)  Line 532 + 0x1e bytes    C++
    myapp.exe!QVector<std::map<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > > >::operator+=(const QVector<std::map<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > > > & l={...})  Line 684    C++
    myapp.exe!MyClass::AppendToLinks(QVector<std::map<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > > > & linksvec={...})  Line 93   C++
```

both of the QVector and Stacks looks like not empty or null
what else can it be ?

Comment: My experience is that errors of this kind (reading from an address suspiciously close to 0) almost always result from passing a null pointer or null reference. (Yes, you can create a null reference, sometimes with alarming ease. It's UB of course, but that doesn't mean they don't happen. It just means that behavior is undefined.)

Answer (score 2):

If `mutex` is protecting access to `m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack`, you should maintain the lock across the call to `if(m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack.size()>0)`.  So inside the `try` block you want something like:

```
static QMutex mutex;
QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack += linksvec;
return !m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack.isEmpty();
```

However, this still looks a bit suspicious.  If this is the *only* place `m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack` is accessed in your program, you're OK with the mutex being a local static object.  But if it's accessed anywhere else, `mutex` will not be available to protect `m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack`.

If `m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack` *is* accessed elsewhere, you'll need to have the same mutex available at those places too (e.g. make it a class member).

Comment: I would just add that the QMutexLocker doesn't require that you unlock it before returning. The beauty of using a QMutexLocker is that it automatically unlocks its QMutex in its destructor, saving you from the need to remember to manually unlock it at every exit point.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like `m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack` is getting accessed in another function (by a reader that pulls links from your QStack?) and that location is not protected by the mutex. Thus when you try to redefine `m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack` while another thread is using it, you get an error.

When you redefine your container it must first destroy its previous contents before accepting the new contents. If container is currently being used, you can see why this might be a problem. Why do you create a temporary stack instead of just appending to `m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack` directly?

Also, you're mixing QVector and QStack in that function. Shouldn't be a problem, but it might be depending on how you access it later.